# Is possible to have a autocomplete function in a ModelChoiceField in Django forms?

Tags: python, django

For example, if a ModelChoiceField has too many items, to find a specific item with autocomplete is easier.

Comment: Is this just a yes or no question?

Comment: No, is for explaining too

Comment: I found another solution easier, here: https://select2.org/

Comment: This isn't duplicate, 'ModelChoiceField' makes things different and more complicated than just autocomplete of input field.